# Prevent AutoConfiguration of all included Spring Cloud dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Excluding several `AutoConfiguration` classes in Spring Boot is easy. Just exclude it from the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration.class,
})
```

But how can all `AutoConfiguration` from the package `org.springframework.cloud` can be excluded without adding all Spring Clouds `AutoConfiguration` classes to the exclude? That would be dozens if not hundred entries. And it would not be future proof as with every new Spring Cloud version new `AutoConfiguration` classes come along.

Using `@ComponentScan` would only work if `@SpringBootApplication` respective `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is not used. But that would remove all the convenient auto configuration capabilities, too.

Is there a way to achieve that programmatically? And how?

---

Removing Spring Clouds dependencies from the application is unfortunately not a feasible solution.

Comment: why are the dependencies there if they can't be removed?

Comment: @spencergibb For a very special use case.

Comment: @spencergibb The application can be configured as local worker, as delegate that delegates the work to workers or both in a mixed mode. In the first case no Spring Cloud is necessary. For the second and third case Eureka, Ribbon, Feign, Hysterix, and all the others are necessary and so the dependencies. I could have asked "How to disable all of Spring Cloud AutoConfiguration unless a flag is set in the properties", too.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to exclude all classes from auto configuration ?

Most of the beans in Autoconfigurations are @conditional , they will not be created if you are providing your own.

Anyway you can look into AutoConfigurationImportSelector . As of now Spring boot allow only class and name for @EnableAutoConfigurtion exclude . if you want to write customize "AutoConfigurationImportSelector" , you can subclass and filter exclude by package after writing your own extended interface for EnableAutoConfiguration to write package method.

As I mentioned this will be the last thing I would like to do . just check @conditional dependency for auto configuration and provide your own beans is better solution.